# PowerShell Azure Function import module error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to import the "Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell" module in my PowerShell Azure Function App. The import is successful but the following command in my "run.ps1" file is throwing an error:

```
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Username $username -Password $pass
```

Following are the contents of function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "Request",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "Response"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following are the contents of host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Following is the Error:

```
2023-04-01T18:44:29Z   [Error]   EXCEPTION: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "WithAuthority": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Exception             : 
    Type           : System.Management.Automation.ExtendedTypeSystemException
    ErrorRecord    : 
        Exception             : 
            Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
            Message : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "WithAuthority": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."
            HResult : -2146233087
        CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
        InvocationInfo        : 
            ScriptLineNumber : 273
            OffsetInLine     : 13
            HistoryId        : -1
            ScriptName       : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1
            Line             : $PublicClientApplication = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder]::Create($ApplicationId).WithAuthority($authBaseuri, $aadAuthAudience, $true).WithDefaultRedirectUri().Build()
                               
            PositionMessage  : At C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1:273 char:13
                               +             $PublicClientApplication = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.Pub …
                               +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156
            PSCommandPath    : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1
            CommandOrigin    : Internal
        ScriptStackTrace      : at Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal, C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1: line 273
                                at Add-PowerAppsAccount, C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1: line 145
                                at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 17
    TargetSite     : 
        Name          : CheckActionPreference
        DeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.9.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
        MemberType    : Method
        Module        : System.Management.Automation.dll
    Message        : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "WithAuthority": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."
    Data           : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    InnerException : 
        Type       : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        Message    : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
        FileName   : System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        TargetSite : 
            Name          : GetSignature
            DeclaringType : System.Signature, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
            MemberType    : Method
            Module        : System.Private.CoreLib.dll
        Source     : System.Private.CoreLib
        HResult    : -2147024894
        StackTrace : 
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.<get_Signature>g__LazyCreateSignature|24_0()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.SameSignature(MethodBase method1, MethodBase method2)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AddOverload(List`1 previousMethodEntry, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.PopulateMethodReflectionTable(Type type, MethodInfo[] methods, CacheTable typeMethods)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.PopulateMethodReflectionTable(Type type, CacheTable typeMethods, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.GetInstanceMethodReflectionTable(Type type)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.GetDotNetMethodImpl[T](Object obj, String methodName, MemberNamePredicate predicate)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.GetDotNetMethod[T](Object obj, String methodName)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.GetMember[T](Object obj, String memberName)
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.BaseGetMember[T](Object obj, String memberName)
    Source         : System.Management.Automation
    HResult        : -2146233087
    StackTrace     : 
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal], ExtendedTypeSystemException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal
InvocationInfo        : 
    MyCommand        : Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal
    ScriptLineNumber : 145
    OffsetInLine     : 5
    HistoryId        : 1
    ScriptName       : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1
    Line             : Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal -Audience $Audience -Endpoint $Endpoint -Username $Username -Password $Password -TenantID $TenantID -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint -ClientSecret $ClientSecret -ApplicationId $ApplicationId
                       
    PositionMessage  : At C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1:145 char:5
                       +     Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal -Audience $Audience -Endpoint $Endpo …
                       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156
    PSCommandPath    : C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1
    InvocationName   : Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal
    CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at Add-PowerAppsAccountInternal, C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1: line 273
                        at Add-PowerAppsAccount, C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2304011814374714419.r\Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell\2.0.156\Microsoft.PowerApps.AuthModule.psm1: line 145
                        at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 17
PipelineIterationInfo : 




2023-04-01T18:44:30Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Failed, Id=a1cf6e48-da48-48ca-bd65-a4463d3ac217, Duration=3675ms)
```

Comment: What is your endpoint? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/add-powerappsaccount?view=pa-ps-latest

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this module before but the requirements stated in the docs on MS Learn state you need to use PowerShell `v5.x`. Azure Functions runs on the `v7.x` runtime.

This seems to correlate with the error message you're getting.

`"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."`

This module (akin to other MS modules) must rely on a prompt or popup authentication box which is not possible in `v7.x` PowerShell.

You can however call out to Windows PowerShell within Azure Functions by adding `-UseWindowsPowerShell` to your import module command.

Not sure if the authentication within the module lets you use SPN authentication which will bypass MFA prompts however.

An alternative is to use Azure Automation Runbooks which do have a `v5.1` runtime available if you can't get them to work in Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly installed using below command and followed [Document](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell/2.0.1):

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
```

[image]

Then Imported with following command:

[image]

Then when I run it in run.ps1, I got it run successful as below:

[image]

- One of the reason you are getting that error may be because of endpoint as @jdweng mentioned.
- Another reason maybe because you have not installed the module with admin rights and not rightly imported it. If you have imported it rightly you get required output as I have got.

For further refer [reference1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/add-powerappsaccount?view=pa-ps-latest).